# When to use const or var or let and lambda expresion internals

Tags: javascript

```
groups= [];

getGroup(id){
    const s = groups.find(t => t.id === id);
    return s;
}

getGroup(id){
    var s = groups.find(t => t.id === id);
    return s;
}


getGroup(id){
    let s = groups.find(t => t.id === id);
    return s;
}
```

1. Is there any logic/reason to define `s` with `var` or `let` in such a situation?
2. What does js do in background of the code in lambda expression?
   Does it keep the values of the `group` in some data struct that can handle this fast and avoid some `forEach` loop ?

Comment: Read about [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var), [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) and [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) in JavaScript.

Comment: You should refer [MDN declarations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements)

Comment: *"Is there any logic/reason to define 's' as var or let in such a situation?"* -- in the code you posted there is no difference between `var`, `let` and `const`. To see the differences you need to use them in larger functions.

Comment: @axiac: i read the MDN - and i understand that the const is the right here but behind this, is there some reason to define read only object as something else ? maybe to optimaiz the memory ? the const/let/var will collect by GC in same way ?

Comment: Read about [function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) and [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). They are slightly different here and there but, in essence, they are functions.

Comment: `const s` ensures `s` is not assigned a new value during the existence of the `s` variable. `s` keeps a reference to an object and the garbage collector doesn't care about `s` (be it a `var`, `let` or `const`). `s` is destroyed when the function returns. The garbage collector cares about the object pointed by `s` and its lifetime is different than the lifetime of `s`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var` is scoped to the *nearest* function block, whereas `let` is scoped to the *nearest* enclosing block.

Let's assume you have a function, and inside that function there's a for-loop. If you define and declare the iterator using `var` you could access it outside the function:

```
function foo() {  
  for(var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    console.log(i);
  }

  // i is 6
  console.log(i);
}
```

If you use `let` instead, `i` will be scoped only to the nearest enclosing block which is the for-loop:

```
function foo() {  
  for(let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    console.log(i);
  }

  // i is undefined
  console.log(i);
}
```

But as a general rule, I almost never use `var` over `let` at least when I am using ES2015. That said, I cannot really think of a case where `var` would make sense and `let` not. Also, if you need to re-assign a variable, go with `let` and if the variable is never re-assigned use `const`.

Keep in mind tho that `const` does only mean immutabilty for primitive values and not for objects, meaning that you can still change property on an object even though you used `const`. It only guards from re-assigning the variable.

Personally, in most cases, I use `const`.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple good resources which provide more details on this [[link1](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-es6-var-let-or-const-ba58b8dcde75), [link2]](https://dzone.com/articles/javascript-difference-between-var-let-and-const-ke). Summary below:

- **let**: Block scope and initialization is optional.
- **const**: Block scope and initialization is required.
- **var**: Assignment is optional and its not block scoped.

Relating to your **lambda expression** - these are arrow functions in javascript and provide shorter syntax for function expression.

---

Now given some context, answers inline to your queries:

- Is there any logic/reason to define s with `var` or `let` in such a situation?

  - `var` is much more relaxed in terms of constrain as described above, so any variable in global scope with same identifier will be affected. `let` keeps this block scoped.
- What does js do in background of the code in lambda expression? Does it keep the values of the group in some data struct that can handle this fast and avoid some forEach loop ?

  - The above lambda expression is just function declaration. The `find` function here takes the arrow function to perform the boolean check.

Answer (score -1):

let and const key are same only differencs are

let key words is block scoped it can access inside the block and same const as wll we cannot  change the value directly of const variable but we can change the reference of object.