# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null after the page loads

Tags: javascript

I know this has been asked so many times, but i couldn't find the answer for my scenerio. Below is my code. I'm getting this error in the last line inside `findPattern` function. But i have that `ID` created inside `createMyArea` as `textArea += 'id="P'+app_page_id+'_VALUE'+key+'"`. But why this is not finding the `ID`? Please let me know what i'm doing wrong here. I'm loading this after the page loads

```
var app_page_id         = 40;
var app_pattern_page_id     = 32;
var app_id;
var checksum;
var lang;

$(document).ready(function() {
    app_id = $("#pFlowId").val();
    checksum = $("#pInstance").val();

    createMyFlow();

    function createMyFlow(){
        var result = new htmldb_Get(null, $v('pFlowId'), 'APPLICATION_PROCESS='+getAllLanguagesProc,  $v('pFlowStepId'));
        lang = jQuery.parseJSON(result.get()).lang;
        createMyArea();
        result = loadDataFromMyOra();
        if(result !== null)
            findPattern(result);
    }

    function createMyArea(){
        var textArea;
        for ( var key in lang){
            textArea = '<tr><td  align="right"><label for="P'+app_page_id+'_VALUE_'+key+'">';
            textArea += '<span class="optional">Name '+languages[key][0]+': </span></label></td>';
            textArea += '<td  align="left" valign="middle">';
            textArea += '<input type="hidden" name="p_arg_names" />';
            textArea += '<fieldset id="P'+app_page_id+'_VALUE_fieldset_'+key+'" class="textarea" tabindex="-1">';
            textArea += '<input name="p_t04" type="text" maxlength="50" size="32" value=""';
            textArea += 'id="P'+app_page_id+'_VALUE'+key+'" required="" class="text_field"></fieldset>'
            textArea += '</td></tr>';
        $('.formlayout').append(textArea);
        }
    }

    function findPattern(patterns)
    {
        var item = "";
        for ( var key in patterns){
            item = patterns[key]+"";
            item = item.replace(/&#44;/g,",");
            item = item.replace(/&#8220;/g,'"')
            document.getElementById("P"+app_page_id+"_VALUE"+key).value = item;   //error here
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates `document.getElementById("P"+app_page_id+"_VALUE"+key)` is `null`. Work backwards and think of all the reasons it might be null:

- What does `"P"+app_page_id+"_VALUE"+key` evaluate to? Does an element with this id exist in the DOM? (You can manually inspect the DOM tree with browser dev tools, or try running `getElementById()` in the dev console.)
- An element with that id probably doesn't exist. You point out you are trying to create it, but is there any reason that `createMyArea()` might not be working?

  - If `lang` is an empty object, this loop will execute 0 times: `for (var key in lang) ...`
  - The `for` loop iterates on keys of the `lang` object, but inside the loop you access via `languages[key]`. That is a little weird.

Their are *many* more things to check, but this should give you an idea of things to look for. Work backwards and test all your assumptions!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the generated HTML or is it impossible to provide such example?

Also I've noticed that you use `var` way more than you should for your variables. Have a quick read about when to use what [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51152255/when-to-use-const-or-var-or-let-and-lambda-expresion-internal) or [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/var-vs-let-vs-const-in-javascript-2954ae48c037/).

Comment: Not to be picky, but if you give such advice about `var` keyword, you should give more details. The OP didn't add ES6 tag to the question and might as well want to support ES5. If not precised, you can't tell and the advice could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The function that generates the code `createMyArea()` uses the keys in the lang variable

```
for ( var key in lang){
....
textArea += 'id="P'+app_page_id+'_VALUE'+key+'" required="" class="text_field"></fieldset>'
....
```

but in the findPatterns you are checking the id of the document using keys from another variable

```
for ( var key in patterns){
....
document.getElementById("P"+app_page_id+"_VALUE"+key).value = item; 
....
```

If the patterns variable and lang variable don't have the same key, then you will get an error.

To check that, you can

```
console.log ("P'+app_page_id+'_VALUE'+key+'")
```

just before the document.getElementById and see what values is checked there.

Comment: I checked. Both are same values